# TCL/Expect - $argv VS $::argv VS {*}$argv

Tags: tcl, expect

What is difference between following variables:

```
$argv
$::argv
{*}$argv
```

First two are possible to print via `puts` command and they returns following output:

```
param0 param1 {param 2} param3
param0 param1 {param 2} param3
```

The arguments that was passed to script were:

```
param0 param1 "param 2" param3
```

The last one end up with error:

```
wrong # args: should be "puts ?-nonewline? ?channelId? string"
    while executing
"puts {*}$argv"
```

I've done some research in this area using following code:

```
if {[array exists $argv]} {
  puts "\$argv IS ARRAY"
} else {
  puts "\$argv IS NOT AN ARRAY"
}

if {[string is list $argv]} {
  puts "\$argv IS LIST"
} else {
  puts "\$argv IS NOT LIST"
}

if {[array exists $::argv]} {
  puts "\$::argv IS ARRAY"
} else {
  puts "\$::argv IS NOT AN ARRAY"
}

if {[string is list $::argv]} {
  puts "\$::argv IS LIST"
} else {
  puts "\$::argv IS NOT LIST"
}

if {[array exists {*}$argv]} {
  puts "{*}\$::argv IS ARRAY"
} else {
  puts "{*}\$::argv IS NOT AN ARRAY"
}

if {[string is list {*}$argv]} {
  puts "{*}\$::argv IS LIST"
} else {
  puts "{*}\$::argv IS NOT LIST"
}
```

The last two if-else statements which contain `{*}$argv` ends with following error:

```
wrong # args: should be "array exists arrayName"
    while executing
"array exists {*}$argv"
    invoked from within
"if {[array exists {*}$argv]} {
  puts "{*}\$::argv IS ARRAY"
} else {
  puts "{*}\$::argv IS NOT AN ARRAY"
}"
```

Commenting out those two statements shows that `$argv` and `$::argv` are lists:

```
argv IS NOT AN ARRAY
$argv IS NOT AN ARRAY
argv IS LIST
$argv IS LIST
```

Both those lists can be traversed as standard list e.g.:

```
foreach item $argv {
  puts $item
}
```

or

```
foreach item $::argv {
  puts $item
}
```

Attempt to traverse `{*}$argv` the same way leads to following error again:

```
wrong # args: should be "foreach varList list ?varList list ...? command"
    while executing
"foreach item {*}$argv {
  puts $item
}"
```

I am using TCL version 8.5

Comment: This question concerns the fundamentals of Tcl syntax. You should read the documentation closely (Tcl syntax: https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/Tcl.htm, Tcl tutorial: https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/tcltutorial.html); things like the global namespace (`::`) and argument expansion (`{*}`) are explained there. StackOverflow is not a site dedicated to basic language training.

Comment: If you've got any followup questions to this, _ask them in a new question_ and link back to this one. That's good Stack Overflow style.

Answer (score 5):

> What is difference between following variables:
>
> ```
> $argv
> $::argv
> {*}$argv
> ```

There are two types of difference here.

### Unqualified and Qualified Variables

In Tcl, unqualified and qualified variables can be a bit different, but it depends on the context (in a pretty simple way though). Firstly, a qualified variable name is one that contains at least one `::` within it. If the variable name (the thing *after* the `$` — in Tcl, `$` just means “read this variable now and use its contents here”) starts with `::`, it is an absolute variable name, otherwise a qualified variable name is a relative variable name and is resolved with respect to the current namespace (which you can find out with `namespace current` if you're uncertain). Absolute variable names always refer to the same thing, in all contexts. Thus, `::argv` is an absolute variable name, and indeed it refers to a variable called `argv` in the top-level, global namespace. That happens to be a variable that `tclsh` and `wish` write their arguments into.

But if there is *no* `::`, it is an *unqualified* variable name. If you are *not* in a procedure (or procedure-like thing, which includes a lambda term such as you'd use with `apply` or the methods defined by various OO systems) then the variable is (mostly) treated as if it was a relative variable name and resolved with respect to the current namespace. `namespace eval` and `namespace code` are two of the things that can change the current namespace (the others are more obscure). All this is *provided you use `variable` to declare all your namespace variables*. Otherwise, you can hit some weird problems with variable resolution which are really nasty. So do use `variable`. Really.

If you are in a procedure(-like entity) though, that unqualified name refers to a *local* variable, whose life is coupled to that of the stack frame pushed on the stack when the procedure is entered. That can be *linked* to variables in other scopes (including the global namespace) through various commands: `global`, `upvar`, `variable`, and `namespace upvar`. However, the actual resolution of the variable is to something local.

Finally, there might also be a custom variable resolver in place. Since you're using Tcl 8.5, the place where you're most likely to see this in use is if you're using Incr Tcl, an object system for Tcl. Custom variable resolvers can do some complex stuff. (If you were using Tcl 8.6, the most likely place to see a custom variable resolver at work is in TclOO. The variable resolver there is *very* conservative and cautious, but allows local variables to be bound to object variables without having to explicitly declare this in each method).

### Normal and Expanding Substitution

The difference between `$argv` and `{*}$argv` is totally different.

`$argv` is a normal substitution. It says “read this variable here and use the contents of it instead”. It can be used in the middle of a word, so `$argv$argv$argv` is a thing, consisting of the concatenation of the contents of the `argv` variable three times.

`{*}`, when placed at the start of a word (it's not special elsewhere), marks that word for *expansion*. When a word is expanded, it's parsed as a Tcl list after all other normal substitutions have been done, and the words of that list are used as words in the resulting command being built up. `{*}$argv` is a degenerate case where the remainder of the word is just the a read from a variable; the words that are used in the command are the elements of the list in the `argv` variable. Since that's normally a list, this is all hunky-dory.

Here's an example:

```
set abc {a b c}
set dabcf [list d $abc f]
puts $dabcf;       # ===> “d {a b c} f”

set eabcg [list e {*}$abc g]
puts $eabcg;       # ===> “e a b c g”
```

See the difference? One produces three elements in the list, the other produces *five*. It makes even more sense with something somewhat longer:

```
set options {
    -foreground blue
    -background yellow
    -text "This is eye-watering stuff!"
}
button .b1 {*}$options -command {puts "Ouch 1"}
button .b2 {*}$options -command {puts "Ouch 2"}
button .b3 {*}$options -command {puts "Ouch 3"}
pack .b1 .b2 .b3
```

With expansion, that all Just Works™. Without, you'd have to do something horrific with `eval`:

```
eval [list button .b1] [lrange $options 0 end] [list -command {puts "Ouch 1"}]
# etc.
```

This was difficult to get right, and tedious, so it caused *lots* of people (including Tcl and Tk maintainers!) many problems because they tended to take shortcuts and get it wrong. It was to address this that expansion syntax was created in Tcl 8.5 to make this all less error prone. (The prototypical example in plain Tcl tends to involve things with `exec`, and meant that quite a few people actually had security holes because of this.)

As a bonus, using `{*}` is much faster than using `eval` since expansion can guarantee that it is never doing complicated reparsing of things. In Tcl, faster virtually always correlates with safer.

Note that this is independent of whether the variable is qualified. Yes, that means that you can also have `{*}$::argv` if you want.

Answer (score 2):

You confuse the effects of substitution with the effects of argument expansion.

Please study the Dodekalogue http://wiki.tcl.tk/10259.

You mix the Rule #5: Argument Expansion (the {*} thing) with Variable Substitution (Rule #8).

The three forms you listed above are equivalent to the following:

```
$argv   -> [set argv]
```

Get the value of a simple variable in the currently active scope.

```
$::argv -> [namespace eval :: { set argv }] -> [set ::argv]
```

Get the value of the variable in the namespace `::` (the global namespace)

```
{*}$argv -> [eval [set argv]]
```

Expand the variables content to multiple arguments.